# Web.config Transformation- VS Extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I was using a visual studio extension named "FAST KOALA" in the past to help myself for debugging easily an asp.net web application by transforming environment variables in web.config based on project configuration in Visual Studio 2015. Now, we use Visual Studio 2017 and that extension doesn't support VS 2017 yet. I'm looking for an extension that can help me transform web.config file when debugging (F5) in VS 2017 version. FYI- I know VS supports web.config transformation when publishing code from VS

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah/

Comment: Clearly it has experimental support for VS2017 for a while, https://github.com/stimpy77/FastKoala/releases

Comment: Visual Studio does it natively. Why not just use that? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

Comment: @JuanR Maybe you should try it out yourself. VS does not do that natively, unfortunately.

Comment: @LexLi: Maybe I am not understanding what he wants. What exactly is it that cannot be done with VS?

Comment: @JuanR Read the description https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JonDaviswijitscom.FastKoala-WebAppconfigXMLtransforms and keywords like "before build" and "after build".

Comment: @LexLi: Thank you. I understand now. This is simple enough to implement manually in the project file: https://sebnilsson.com/blog/asp-net-transform-web-config-with-debug-release-on-build/

Comment: @JuanR, thanks. That is exactly what I was looking to transform web.config on build-time. I'll try that link to see if it works for me.

Comment: BTW, @Crowcoder - On slow cheetah extension page, it only shows how to transform app.config files. I am looking to transform both (app.config and web.config) on run-time

Comment: @JuanR it works like a charm. I like this solution as it modifies the project files directly rather than relying on an external tool. Thanks

Comment: @BhupinderSingh: No problem. I am happy to help.